# Use parameter mutliple time but with limit in docopt

Tags: docopt

I want to format my command usage with docopt.

I found out that

```
<parameter>...
```

means that you can write a parameter multiple time.
My problem is, that I have an argument that you can repeat multiple times but it has a limit. I don't want to write

```
<parameter> [<parameter> <parameter> <parameter> <parameter> <parameter> <parameter>]
```

with the correct count of the

```
<parameter>
```

tag. Is there a shorter way to specify that you can use the parameter mutliple times but the maximum is 15 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't specify a maximum number of occurrences of a pattern in docopt. You can only specify a minimum. You will have to deal with that afterwards (or write  X time).